# C++ call template function of class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have error "expected primary-expression before 'int'" and "expected ';' before 'int'" in this code, does anyone know why?

```
struct cpu
{
    template<class T> static void fce() {}
};

template<class _cpu>
struct S
{    
    void fce() 
    {  
        _cpu::fce<int>(); //error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
                          //error: expected ';' before 'int'
    }
};

int main()
{
    S<cpu> s;
    s.fce();
}
```

Comment: Try  _cpu::template fce<int>(); to treat fce as a dependent template name.

Comment: @0x499602D2 better answer lol

Answer (score 3):

```
_cpu::template fce<int>();
```

Try the above.

Since _cpu is a `template` parameter, the compiler does not recognize that `fce` may be the name of a `member function` - hence it interprets the `<` as a less than symbol.
In order for the compiler to recognize the function template call, add the `template` quantifier: